# 2.83: assign same materials for objects created by array modifier

Tags: materials, modifiers

How do I assign same materials for objects created by array modifier? I created three houses by the modifier and want to assign a same color to their roof.

Comment: have you applied the modifier?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your reaction.

Comment: So by default, if you've given a material to the roof of the original object, all the roofs should have the same material

Comment: If you're trying to assign the material AFTER you've applied the modifier, select all the roofs and make sure the one that has the material is the active object. (by selecting it last e.g.) Then, press Ctrl + L and select Materials.

Comment: if you didn't give any material to the original object, a thing you can try is select all the objects (if they are separate), switch to Edit mode, select the roof of one of the houses and press Ctrl G > Normals (or test the other options), it may help to automatically select all the other roofs if they are a bit tilted

Comment: Thanks both of you. Assume the number of houses are more than three(like one hundred), then I prefer to avoid selecting all the roofs. If  then how should I assign a material? If possible I hope that I have only to assign a material to the original object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your house base model is a continuous mesh (no loose parts), once the modifier is applied, go into edit mode, select everything and press <kbd>P</kbd> > *By Loose Parts*.

Go back into object mode with <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

With everything still selected, Right click > Set Origin > To geometry.

Press <kbd>CTRL+ L</kbd> > Object Data. Now when you modify one object's materials, they will all update.

In the end, while everything is still selected, go to *Object > Relations > Make Single User > Object & Data* and then you will be able to tweak each individual house separately.

Obviously it is better to do it before applying the modifier to avoid any of this.

PS, next time please take more time to write your question so there is less back and forth in the comments :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution and advice.